# How do I read from external files in JS Bin?

Tags: javascript

I've been doing Code Year at Codecademy and I wanted to start practicing Javascript for myself, but I've been having a tough time figuring out some basic issues.

For my first project, I want to read in from a spreadsheet.  I can't figure out how to access the data from its original source online, so I thought I would just save it as a text file.  My question, then, is how to read from that.

So it looks like you can't read local files in Javascript.  (Although apparently that's changing with HTML5? I don't have any familiarity with that.)  So do I have to upload the text file someplace?  Can I upload files to JS Bin?  If not, does anyone have any recommendations for where I can upload the text file?  And either way, once I do, what's the code to read from it?

Thanks in advance.  I am sure this question is riddled with misstatements and improprieties, but I've spent a significant amount of time on this and I can't find anything that seems to answer my question.  I honestly thought it would be something simple, like "var inputfile = c:\file.txt" but that seems not to be the case.  I am totally lost.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't. File system and storages in Javascript (or rather the client) is sandboxed.

That means you can only read what is written there in the first place. This has to do with security.

You will need to drop (or select) the local files into the browser and have some mechanism there to receive the drop/selection and store the file to one of the local storing mechanisms such as `indexedDB` or `file API` (the latter currently only supported in Chrome). For text files `localStorage` works fine too.

Resources:
http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/
http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/
http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/

The other option is to upload it to server and download it from there when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

When you get to this point in your development, its time to run your own webserver for testing as it makes things much easier. If you must insist on doing it your way, uploading the file to a file hosting site and reading it in is still possible. Codecademy is great for getting started, but when you get into dealing with persistent data sources (either files or databases) its time to get web hosting or set up your own test server.

Even then you don't REALLY need your own test server, just a folder on your computer. You can access the files with File://, and link in the file you want to read as a relative path. If the .txt file is in the same directory, you just link it in as "Example.txt" when you open the html file in that directory.